# A task was cancelled error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am using `REST` call, the code is like:

```
public bool restfunc(string id)
{
    var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunAsync(id)).Result; //RunAsync(id).Wait();
    return true;
}

public static Task RunAsync(string id)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic result = null;
        string pathValue = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2G2APIUrl"];
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pathValue);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            Task responsetask = null;
            var jobid = id.Split('_')[1];
            client.GetAsync("OnTranscriptionStarted/" + jobid).ContinueWith((requesttask) =>
               {
                   responsetask = requesttask;
                   HttpResponseMessage resp = requesttask.Result; //HERE ERR OCCUR
                   resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                   resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((readtask) =>
                   {
                       result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readtask.Result);
                   });
               });
        }
        return result;
```

Doubt:

1. I have API in `pathvalue`..I have to write `pathvalue` in
   `GetAsync()` or function name and id which I want to call?

Help me out from this problem please..

Comment: Do you need either `pathValue` or the function name? Your question isn't clear. Or, do you need to concat both together?

Comment: I need `pathvalue/functionname/value` @YuvalItzchakov

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for that:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(
        "http", pathValue, 80, string.Format("OnTranscriptionStarted/{0}", jobId));
client.GetAsync(builder.Uri.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you change it? just remove the `http`.